# Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers....?

Tags: java, jboss, aix

We have next exception during starting of our application under JBoss on AIX:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs fo

12:56:25,055 INFO  [STDOUT] r trusted CAs

        at javax.crypto.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)

        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)

        ... 83 more

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted 
signers!

        at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)

        at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)

        at javax.crypto.b.access$600(Unknown Source)

        at javax.crypto.b$0.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:246)
```

**if we use this version of java**

> java version "1.5.0"
>
> Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap64dev-20090707 (SR10 ))
>
> IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc64-64 j9vmap6423-20090707 (JIT enabled)
>
> J9VM - 20090706_38445_BHdSMr
>
> JIT  - 20090623_1334_r8
>
> GC   - 200906_09)
>
> JCL  - 20090705

**And we do not have any exceptions on the same AIX with next version of java**

> java version "1.5.0"
>   Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap32dev-20080315 (SR7))
>
> IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223-20080315 (JIT enabled)
>
> J9VM - 20080314_17962_bHdSMr
>
> JIT  - 20080130_0718ifx2_r8
>
> GC   - 200802_08)
>
> JCL  - 20080314

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/security/50/
IBM's SDKs ship with strong but limited jurisdiction policy files.
Unlimited jurisdiction policy files can be obtained from the link above.  The ZIP file should be unpacked and the two JAR files placed in the JRE's jre/lib/security/ directory.  These policy files are for use with IBM developed SDKs.

New IBM SDK Policy files should be downloaded and installed to /usr/java5_64/jre/lib/security directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second environment is a 32bits one.

EDIT: Maybe the 64 bits environment is not enough mature (the problem could be a problem with the VM/OS integration).

Regards.

Comment: AIX 6.1
And I do not have any problem on another RISC with 64 java
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap64dev-20080315 (SR7))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc64-64 j9vmap6423-20080315 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20080314_17962_BHdSMr
JIT  - 20080130_0718ifx2_r8
GC   - 200802_08)
JCL  - 20080314

I think tha problem is in SR10 vs SR7.

Answer (score -1):

Im running osx lion.  I received this error because I had [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784772/java-cipher-package-encrypt-and-decrypt-invalid-key-error/2784955#2784955) the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from java's website.  After getting this error I went back and set the originals back, and the error was resolved.