# Java getting error 'Unhandled exception type XYZ'

Tags: java, macos, jce

I have this code:

```
class Crypt
{
    Key KEY;
    String TD;
    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

public Crypt()
{
    int keyLength = 192;
    keyGen.init(keyLength);
    KEY = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Which when compiles gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
    Unhandled exception type NoSuchPaddingException
    Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
```

When researching the error I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784955/530933).  But after downloading, installing and [verifying](https://groups.google.com/group/jets3t-users/msg/06751e3ffbb4e322) that Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files are up to date I am still getting the error.

Comment: just wanted to put a warning for other osx users.  it seems to me that if you manually update them from java's website you could end up with other errors.  The ones built in should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is very clear and doesn't have anything to do with the unlimited jurisdiction encryption files. It's telling you there are unhandled checked exceptions.

Add `throws Exception` to your constructor so it looks like this:

```
public Crypt() throws Exception
{
    int keyLength = 192;
    keyGen.init(keyLength);
    KEY = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you also install them into /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security?