# Error:Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Im getting this error Error:Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
in Android Studio 0.9.3, any solutions?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Confluence+can+not+start+or+user+can+not+log+in+due+to+javax.crypto.JceSecurity+exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9745323/2600731 was what helped me solve this issue, as apposed to deleting those files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Ensure that the following JAR files does exist in the your JRE:

JRE/lib/security/local_policy.jar
JRE/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
```

Comment: When this happens after a Java upgrade, there may be `*_policy.jar.rpmnew` files in that directory. Copy those over the present files, which are actually those of your previous Java version.