# java.lang.SecurityException: The Jar (/opt/WebSphere/AppServer7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar) is not signed by a trusted signer

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere-7

I'm getting a Jar is not signed by trusted signer issue, when the application is running on WebSphere 7.
However I am not getting an error when I run it locally on Tomcat 7 with the jdk1.6.0_45.

I added `Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);` in order to use BouncyCastles's provider instead of the default one. This allows us to hit a web service that is forcing TLSv1.0 as the SSL Protocol.

**Suspected Cause**

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

**The Class where the error happens**

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Outbound_Service", targetNamespace = WS_NAMESPACE)
public class SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl extends Service implements SmsOutBoundClient {

    private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    private static final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 30000;

    private static final QName serviceName = new QName(WS_NAMESPACE, "Outbound_Service");

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl.class); 

    private URL smsUrl;
    private EnterpriseTextMessagingOutboundPortType mService;

    private String applicationID;
    private String refNumber;
    private String source;
    private String deliveryReceiptRegisteredInd;

    static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    public SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl(URL wsdlUrl){
        super(wsdlUrl, serviceName); <<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR Happens at this line
        this.smsUrl=wsdlUrl;
        this.mService = this.getEmsSoapHttpPort();
        setRequestContextProperties();
    }

    public SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl(URL wsdlUrl, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlUrl, serviceName);
        this.smsUrl=wsdlUrl;
        this.mService = this.getEmsSoapHttpPort(features);
        setRequestContextProperties();
    }
***** Etc. *****
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Jar (/opt/WebSphere/AppServer7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar) is not signed by a trusted signer
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLJsseUtil.a(SSLJsseUtil.java:93)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLJsseUtil.b(SSLJsseUtil.java:90)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:6)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:16)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:19)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.<init>(b.java:83)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:11)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:6)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:957)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$3.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:319)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.openConnection(WSDL4JWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getURLConnection(WSDL4JWrapper.java:296)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.access$000(WSDL4JWrapper.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$2.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:306)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getPrivilegedURLConnection(WSDL4JWrapper.java:304)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:184)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.<init>(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1191)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:71)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:67)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.outbound.SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl.<init>(SmsOutBoundClientWSImpl.java:57)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.SmsService.getSmsOutBoundClient(SmsService.java:762)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.SmsService.createSmsOutboundProcessor(SmsService.java:672)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.SmsService.processTrackEventsAndSaveNotificationRequest(SmsService.java:495)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.SmsService.processTrackRequest(SmsService.java:474)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.SmsService.nonMobileProviderRequest(SmsService.java:196)
    at gov.xxxx.pts.api.sms.ws.NonMobileProviderRequestWs.nonMobileProviderRequest(NonMobileProviderRequestWs.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    ... 1 more
```

**Full Stack Trace:**
Full Stack trace is too large for Stack Overflow.
http://pastebin.com/qkvsqR5z

Comment: I think there is problem with your mixing `runtime and policy file versions` this problem is only because of some policy file version Jars. What i can expect or experience..

Comment: Please either update your `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files` or replace your `jars` by downloading it from any trusted sites. This might help you out

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure TLS with out-of-the-box WebSphere without resorting to using Bouncy Castle. It is unclear what effect Bouncy Castle has on WebSphere. From administrative console:

1. Go to SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations
2. Select the SSL Configuration, it might be necessary to do it once for each
3. Go to Quality of protection (QoP)
4. In the box labeled "Protocol", select TLS.

Also with out of the box WebSphere, you could try `<WAS_HOME>/java/bin/jarSigner -verify <WAS_HOME>/plugins/com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar`. If it does not verify, there is something wrong with the installation.

Comment: Michael Cheng - Is that for the Server SSL Configurations or the Client SSL Configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `jdk v1.6.**` and `Tomcat V_7` but there might be a chance that whatever `jar` you try to add to your `lib` is compiled in `jdk v1.7` or **upper** versions.

So, this issues came only because of this `reason`. You may download a `jar` which is compiled in `java V_6.**` or Update your `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files`. Either of these two may solve your problem.

[Java jce7 Link to download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

You may find your solution [The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745193/java-lang-securityexception-the-jurisdiction-policy-files-are-not-signed-by-a-t) Too.